# Filtering out SQAlchemy query with group_by based on column value being > 0

Tags: python, filter, sqlalchemy, where-clause

I am trying to filter out this SQLAlchemy query to only return records where avg_3d_perf > 0

Here is a query I am using:

```
query = query.with_entities(func.max(Signals_light.id).label('id'),Signals_light.symbol,func.max(Signals_light.close).label('close'),func.max(Signals_light.volume).label('volume'),func.max(Signals_light
            .total_change).label('total_change'),func.max(Signals_light.strength).label('strength'),func.max(Signals_light.created_at).label('created_at'),func.max(Signals_light.window_mins).label('window_mins'),
            func.max(Signals_light.pattern).label('pattern'),func.max(Signals_light.pattern_type).label('pattern_type'),func.max(Signals_light.sentiment).label('sentiment'),func.avg(func.nullif(Signals_light.avg_3d_perf,0)).label('avg_3d_perf'),
            func.count(Signals_light.symbol).label('signals_count')).group_by(Signals_light.symbol)
```

All I need to do is filter the results from this query above to only keep records where avg_3d_Perf > 0

I tried using statements like `query = query.filter(avg_3d_Perf > 0).all()` on top of this large query but I think I need to apply this filter differently somehow.

I also tried to add `.having(avg_3d_perf > 0)` to the end of the query but it does not work either.

Comment: what is wrong with the results you get from `query.filter(Signals_light.avg_3d_perf > 0).all()`?

Comment: Thank you @JoostDöbken for looking at this. I get a 500 error, the query fails if I add `query = query.filter(Signals_light.avg_3d_perf > 0).all()` right after the query I shared in the main message.

Comment: I had read that, but what does the error message say? Python or Sqlalchemy don't return 500s themselves

Comment: This is not going to helpful...but unfortunately I am not seeing any error in Python when I run the file. The Query output is correct in my IDE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `query = query.having(func.avg(func.nullif(Signals_light.avg_3d_perf,0)) > 0)` after the main query solved my issue.

Comment: Congratulations on solving your own problem! Make sure you accept your answer to indicate this question had a viable solution.